# connection to srv1.srv-stat.com error in Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, connection, osx-mavericks

I'm using mavericks and Chrome. When looking at Chrome console I get this strange error saying:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED https://srv1.srv-stat.com/i/?tid=235&hash=oolvhf&subid=1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR https://srv1.srv-stat.com/i/?tid=199&hash=8ktxrl&subid=1
```

Referring to swl_core.js file.

I blocked the domain connection in my hosts file. But I wonder what is it? How can I remove it forever.

Thank you.

Comment: It is saying it is unable to connect to that server. Which is what should happen if you blocked the site right?

Comment: yes, but I wonder why it tries always to connect to this server: https://srv1.srv-stat.com/

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by clearing Google cache files.